# Unable to add annotations to charts within google sheets using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create line and area chart png images with google app scripts using data within a google sheet.  I am able to successfully create the graphs, but unable to add an annotation field in app scripts that can be added using java script.

Below is the app script code, I would expect I'd be able to add something like `.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "annotationText")` or `.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'})` like is done within javascript.  Neither work in the code below, and there seems to be no way to declare via google script that a column is assigned to the "annotation" role.  Is there some undocumented way to add annotations to charts via google scripts?  I could not find any documentation for assigning annotation roles to columns using google script, but it seems that this would be possible.  Does anyone know how to do this via google scripts?

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Month")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "In Store")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Online")
       .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "annotationText")
       .addRow(["January", 10, 1, "cold!"])
       .addRow(["February", 12, 1,""])
       .addRow(["March", 20, 2, ""])
       .addRow(["April", 25, 3, "showers"])
       .addRow(["May", 30, 4,""])
       .build();

   var chartBlob = Charts.newAreaChart()
       .setDataTable(data)
       .setStacked()
       .setRange(0, 40)
       .setTitle("Sales per Month")
       .build()
       .getAs('image/PNG');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Charts Service exposes a limited portion of the Google Visualization API. Annotations are not supported, for example.

You can add annotations if you use client-side javascript (in a dialog, for example) with the Visualization API. Unfortunately, that would not fit your save-as-image approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping to NOT see this answer, but appreciate your confirmation.  Is there a way I can open a feature request to have chart service expose this capability?  This would be a great addition to Charts in google scripts.

Comment: I know it wasn't what you hoped, but glad it helped. Feature requests and bug reports for Google Apps Script can be added to the [issues list](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list). I've been converting visualizations away from Charts myself, to get access to visualization types not supported there. ([Blogged](http://wp.me/p6qe1H-i) about it today, in fact.) I had been questioning the continuing support for the Charts Service altogether until I saw your question. Interesting case.

Comment: Appreciate your help, I submitted bug https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5239.  The chart service is extremely useful when using google sheets as a mechanism to graph data retrieved from Big Query, and allow me to automatically send emails with this data / graphs included in the html email.

Comment: I see that. I think it would be worth the effort to find a way to get the visualization another way. It's not like feature requests are acted on promptly.

Comment: Yes, agree with you, I'm not banking on this support in google-app-scripts any time soon.  We are working on a parallel effort to be able to utilize javascript to render these charts and distribute through email, but that is a few months off yet.  In the mean time, I'll make do with google-app-script, unfortunately without annotations.