# How to add dynamic annotations to a column chart?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to add annotations to a google spreadsheet column chart from GoogleAppsScript. Basically what I want is to dynamically add some text on top of one of the columns in the chart to highlight that specific data point. I found the following documentation, but I think I am missing the point. I am confused on how to properly use the setoptions method:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

I have my code below. In the commented code below, I was trying to add a 4th series and set it's role to annotation. That does not seem to work :

```
function updateHistoricalChart() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dashboardSheet = sss.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
var historicalChart = dashboardSheet.getCharts()[0];
var historicalChartBuilder = historicalChart.modify();
//var range = dashboardSheet.getRange('AE14:AE200');
//historicalChartBuilder.addRange(range);
//historicalChartBuilder.setOption('series',{3:{role:'annotation'}});
dashboardSheet.updateChart(historicalChartBuilder.build());
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Edit:

I found the following thread: [Unable to add annotations to charts within google sheets using app script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497372/unable-to-add-annotations-to-charts-within-google-sheets-using-app-script?rq=1)

It looks like this can't be done.

Comment: Look at the column chart examples [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options).  Cycle through the examples until you see one with annotations and then click "Code it yourself on JSFiddle".

Comment: None of them seem to have a specific example that suits me. Also, there seems to be a difference between an embedded chart and google.visualization library. All the examples are for google.visualization not embedded charts.

Comment: The options are very similar though and they both reference the same table.

Comment: It looks like it can't be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497372/unable-to-add-annotations-to-charts-within-google-sheets-using-app-script?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I really appreciate that.