# Add label to stacked column chart in google apps script chart services?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

How does one add labels to a stacked column chart in Script Services?  For example in the code below, the 2016 column would have '5', '6', '2' and '0' for SQL, COI, COD and GIA stacks, respectively.  All columns would be labeled.  Currently there are no column labels.

I have read the Chart services [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/), the [visualization reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts) and stack overflow without finding a solution.

```
 var dataTimeline = Charts.newDataTable()
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "SQL")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "COI")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "COD")
  .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "GIA")
  .addRow(["2016", 5, 6, 2, 0])
  .addRow(["2017", 10, 5, 1, 1])
  .addRow(["2018", 7, 8, 0, 1])
  .addRow(["2019", 2,0,0,0])
  .build();

   var timelineChart = Charts.newColumnChart()
       .setTitle('Timeline')
       .setXAxisTitle('Year')
       .setDataTable(dataTimeline)
       .setStacked()
       .setOption('annotation', value)  // Is this close?
       .setColors(["ffc000", "c00000", "558ed5", "00b050"])
       .build();

   var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setTitle('Timeline');
   var imageData = Utilities.base64Encode(timelineChart.getAs('image/png').getBytes());
   var imageUrl = "data:image/png;base64, " + encodeURI(imageData);
   htmlOutput.append("<img border=\"1\" src=\"" + imageUrl + "\">");

   return htmlOutput.getContent();
```

Comment: If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. Your issue might be related to this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31497372/7108653

Comment: Thanks for the help.  So you can't have the column value appear as a label on the column.  I'll scratch my head for a bit on that and then try the visualizations api.  Thanks again.