# Create a horizontal bar based on value in google sheet cell

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I make the length of my blue background be based on my P E R M A scores? the scores range from 0 to 10. I plan to have a max length of my div border to 10 and the length of the background will fluctuate based on the P E R M A scores save in a google sheet range. what are the parameters of div to set the background length and div border length? I want each score to have a horizontal bar that will represent each score. The scores will be emailed with a bar graph like representation of each score. its my first time to code and I have no knowledge in programming.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello,</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Here are your PERMA Profiler test results!</p>
    <p>P Score: <?= P ?></p>
    <div style="background-size:75px;background-color:blue;width:150px;height:25px;border:4px solid #000;   "><p>P Score: <?= P ?></p></div>
    <p>E Score: <?= E ?></p>
    <p>R Score: <?= R ?></p>
    <p>M Score: <?= M ?></p>
    <p>A Score: <?= A ?></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Thanks!</p>
  </body>
</html>

function testResults() {
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('mail_template');  
  //var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange();
  //var email = rng.getValues()[1];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Scores');
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
  var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
  //Logger.log(emailAddress)
  var pScore = sheet1.getRange(i,34).getValue();
  var eScore = sheet1.getRange(i,35).getValue();
  var rScore = sheet1.getRange(i,36).getValue();
  var mScore = sheet1.getRange(i,37).getValue();
  var aScore = sheet1.getRange(i,38).getValue();
  // set the values for the placeholders
  htmlBody.P = pScore;
  htmlBody.E = eScore;
  htmlBody.R = rScore;
  htmlBody.M = mScore;
  htmlBody.A = aScore;
  Logger.log(emailAddress)
  //Logger.log(eScore)}
  //Logger.log(pScore)
  // evaluate and get the html
  var email_html = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    //to: emailAddress,
    to: '',
    subject: 'PERMA Profiler Test Results ',
    htmlBody: email_html,
    replyTo:'',
  });}
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Hi ! Do you really need to have your HTML in a separate file? I think it could be easier for you to have your HTML on your same ```code.gs``` file as a string variable ```var html = '<div>example</div>'``` where you can append whatever value you want such as ```var html = '<div>'+SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets[0].getRange('A1').getValue()+'</div>'. Finally you would just need to use [createTemplate(html)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createtemplatehtml). Would this solution suit your situation?

Comment: thank you. I am a beginner and learning and that's the sample code I saw. I will try to learn your suggestions and combine my code for script and html

Comment: Have you considered creating a [bar chart](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142829?hl=en) in your script (either manually or with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/bar-chart-builder)) and then attaching this chart to your email message? I think that could be easier for you than creating a separate html div for each element changing the background size (as this can get messed up with responsive sites)? Would you be opened to a solution using such a chart instead of your HTML elements?

Comment: bar chart is really what i want. but did not find a tutorial or sample code how to do it yet. If you can give me sample or point to a direction i will highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am including below a simple script to create and send your chart based on your data within the gmail message body. To achieve this I took use of the [data table creator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/data-table-builder) to create a table with my data to then use the [Bar Chart builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/bar-chart-builder) with different features (it is very customizable, please refer to the documentation linked) to create the chart. Finally, I converted this chart into a [Blob](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob) to be able to insert the chart image in HTML.

The important thing here is that you want to reference your inline image in your HTML body in order to link the blob with the image tag using `cid`. The following piece of code has self-explanatory comments:

```js
function myFunction() {

// Here I am simply creating the data, you can get this data range from
// your Spreadsheet or create it like me (simply values for each char of PERMA)
  var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "PERMA")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Score")
    .addRow(["P", 10])
    .addRow(["E", 12])
    .addRow(["R", 20])
    .addRow(["M", 25])
    .addRow(["A", 30])
    .build();

// Create your chart with the correct options and assign your data
 var chartBuilder = Charts.newBarChart()
     .setTitle('PERMA SCORES')
     .setXAxisTitle('PERMA')
     .setYAxisTitle('Score')
     .setDimensions(600, 500)
     .setLegendPosition(Charts.Position.BOTTOM)
     .setDataTable(data);

// convert chart to a blob so that it can be used in the HTML
// Name it if you are going to add more than one inline image
 var chart = chartBuilder.build().getBlob().setName('chart');

// The HTML body of the message. Remember to add an image with the cid reference
// to your inline image that you are going to add, in this case it will correspond to our chart
 var body = "<img src='cid:A' style='width:200px; height:200px;'/>";

// Send mail. Its important that it is an HTML body and that the inline image object key corresponds with the 
// reference in the HTML image tag
 MailApp.sendEmail({to:'Darth.Vader@egs-sbt081.eu',subject:'PERMA Scores',htmlBody:body, inlineImages:{A:chart}});
}
```

Comment: thank you that worked. can i divide the column into constant 10? I want to have 10 vertical lines that will serve as a guide for each score to be interpreted as low average or high...

Comment: ohh nvm its setRange. Thank you once again. Great help

Comment: can you also give a sample code how to place the score inside the bar? I was reading the DataView implementation but I can't seem to understand it...

Comment: Hi ! There is no functionallity to add series annotations just with Apps Script as explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31507838). [This is a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762739) for this functionallity, star it to indicate that you are also affected by it. The only way to can include annotations is either by creating manually the chart in Google Sheets and then converting this chart into an image and send it in the email or using [google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) with Javascript.

Comment: Hi ! If my answer helped you solve your problem please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and/or [upvoting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Thanks !

Comment: i already upvoted you but it wont appear here since I have less than 11 repu but its recorded. I can not find the Answered button

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for considering it. The accept button is just right below the upvote button (the tick mark). You can see where it is more clearly [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks !